# sysbase error converting characters

Tags: sybase

we have a sybase database, it's server side character is iso_1, when we do some batch insert through jdbc, sybase give me folllowing error:

```
error converting character, some character(s) can not be converted.
```

the data being inserted is encoded with GBK. I am not familiar with sybase, and I have googled but no precise solution found.

the data is:

```
<wlxxList>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="151" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/23 01:38:53" JYLSH="MF16000000117" ZCKZXM="贵州中水建设管理股份有限公司" ZCKZH="170022010900007116" ZCKZHKHH="170022010900007116" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ=""/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="152" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/23 01:47:20" JYLSH="MF15300000094" ZCKZXM="贵州中水建设管理股份有限公司" ZCKZH="170022010900007116" ZCKZHKHH="170022010900007116" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="153" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/23 02:05:42" JYLSH="MF18200000113" ZCKZXM="湖南省湘中水利水电工程建设有限公司" ZCKZH="43001510069050000301" ZCKZHKHH="43001510069050000301" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="154" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/23 02:10:04" JYLSH="MF13100000147" ZCKZXM="贵州中水建设管理股份有限公司" ZCKZH="170022010900007116" ZCKZHKHH="170022010900007116" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="155" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="100000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/23 01:32:57" JYLSH="MF13500000173" ZCKZXM="浙江江能建设有限公司" ZCKZH="33001616435050007140" ZCKZHKHH="33001616435050007140" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="156" JYZL="存现" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="30000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/26 00:49:01" JYLSH="2332900000001" ZCKZXM="" ZCKZH="" ZCKZHKHH="" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="江苏华德工程建设有限公司投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="157" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="30000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/26 01:02:30" JYLSH="MF13700000029" ZCKZXM="贵州九川建设发展有限公司" ZCKZH="52001423600052505667" ZCKZHKHH="52001423600052505667" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="158" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="300000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/26 01:26:59" JYLSH="MF18300000021" ZCKZXM="中铁五局（集团）有限公司" ZCKZH="52001423600059666999" ZCKZHKHH="52001423600059666999" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="159" JYZL="存现" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="30000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/26 01:24:34" JYLSH="2332900000009" ZCKZXM="" ZCKZH="" ZCKZHKHH="" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="安徽水安建设集团股份有限公司交纳紫云县水塘、坝寨农田保护工程施工投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="160" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="40000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/26 02:02:20" JYLSH="MF12200000062" ZCKZXM="贵州省黔东南州水利电力勘察设计院" ZCKZH="23603001040000217" ZCKZHKHH="23603001040000217" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="付投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="161" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="10000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/26 01:42:41" JYLSH="MF15900000097" ZCKZXM="贵州黔水工程监理有限责任公司" ZCKZH="23101001040003317" ZCKZHKHH="23101001040003317" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="162" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="30000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/26 02:03:00" JYLSH="MF18400000138" ZCKZXM="贵州中金水利水电工程建设有限公司" ZCKZH="52001423836052502188" ZCKZHKHH="52001423836052502188" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="163" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="30000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/26 02:40:43" JYLSH="MF17900000103" ZCKZXM="青州市水利建筑总公司" ZCKZH="90705000020100019185" ZCKZHKHH="90705000020100019185" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="紫云县水塘、坝寨工程"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="164" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/26 02:10:12" JYLSH="MF11800000135" ZCKZXM="甘肃九洲水电建筑工程有限责任公司" ZCKZH="030701040009018" ZCKZHKHH="030701040009018" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="遵义新区２０１３中央财政小型农田水利项目投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="165" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/26 02:28:47" JYLSH="MF13500000135" ZCKZXM="遵义市水利水电工程建设总公司" ZCKZH="263001040000622" ZCKZHKHH="263001040000622" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="遵义市新蒲新区２０１３年小农水建设项目投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="166" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="300000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/26 01:26:04" JYLSH="MF18900000130" ZCKZXM="甘肃九洲水电建筑工程有限责任公司" ZCKZH="030701040009018" ZCKZHKHH="030701040009018" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="石阡县獐子沟水库Ｃ２标：水源枢纽工程投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="167" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/26 01:59:55" JYLSH="MF14300000147" ZCKZXM="贵州三蒲建设工程有限公司" ZCKZH="132000183349" ZCKZHKHH="132000183349" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="遵义市新浦新区2013年中央财政小型农田水利专项县建设项目施工投"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="168" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="30000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/26 01:43:47" JYLSH="MF13600000173" ZCKZXM="甘肃九洲水电建筑工程有限责任公司" ZCKZH="030701040009018" ZCKZHKHH="030701040009018" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="全国中小河流治理紫云县水塘坝寨农田项目保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="169" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/27 01:32:35" JYLSH="MF14300000027" ZCKZXM="贵州铜仁三江水电建筑施工有限公司" ZCKZH="52001683636050001832" ZCKZHKHH="52001683636050001832" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="遵义市新浦新区2013中央财政小农水项目"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="170" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/27 01:32:11" JYLSH="MF16200000059" ZCKZXM="贵州水利科技开发有限责任公司" ZCKZH="521145000012015004327" ZCKZHKHH="521145000012015004327" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="171" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/27 01:48:37" JYLSH="MF12300000037" ZCKZXM="青海省水利水电勘测设计研究院" ZCKZH="63001883637050003188" ZCKZHKHH="63001883637050003188" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="妙隘水库工程"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="172" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/27 01:37:41" JYLSH="MF18400000047" ZCKZXM="贵州九禹建设项目管理有限公司" ZCKZH="52001433836052500992" ZCKZHKHH="52001433836052500992" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="遵义市新蒲新区2013年小型农田建设项目"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="173" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/27 02:05:34" JYLSH="MF19300000142" ZCKZXM="都匀市匀城水利有限责任公司" ZCKZH="52001654236052507547" ZCKZHKHH="52001654236052507547" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="174" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/27 02:05:34" JYLSH="MF19300000143" ZCKZXM="贵州汇源建筑工程有限公司" ZCKZH="52001674736050000124" ZCKZHKHH="52001674736050000124" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="遵义新蒲新区2013中央财政小型农田水利"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="175" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/27 02:32:18" JYLSH="MF19400000127" ZCKZXM="濮阳兴河水电工程有限公司" ZCKZH="463401040001083" ZCKZHKHH="463401040001083" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="遵义市新浦区１３年中央财政小农水项目保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="176" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="300000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/27 01:32:43" JYLSH="MF13400000164" ZCKZXM="岳阳市君山水利工程建筑安装公司" ZCKZH="608057577922" ZCKZHKHH="608057577922" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="石阡县獐子沟水库水源工程（C2标水源枢纽工程）"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="177" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/27 02:01:31" JYLSH="MF15300000133" ZCKZXM="贵州江河水利电力建设工程有限公司" ZCKZH="52001413600052507473" ZCKZHKHH="52001413600052507473" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="178" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="60000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/27 02:06:23" JYLSH="MF18400000120" ZCKZXM="水利部丹江口水利枢纽管理局建设监理中心" ZCKZH="42001616633050001000" ZCKZHKHH="42001616633050001000" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="黔西县樱桃坪水库工程监理投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="179" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/27 02:00:54" JYLSH="MF15400000153" ZCKZXM="岳阳市君山水利工程建筑安装公司" ZCKZH="608057577922" ZCKZHKHH="608057577922" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="遵义市新浦新区2013年中央财政小型农田水利专项县建设项目施工"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="180" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 01:19:42" JYLSH="MF11100000014" ZCKZXM="三明市水利水电工程有限公司" ZCKZH="13800101040031757" ZCKZHKHH="13800101040031757" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="勿退，稍后发查询"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="181" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 01:00:40" JYLSH="MF12200000012" ZCKZXM="河北省水利水电勘测设计研究院" ZCKZH="305101201090073343" ZCKZHKHH="305101201090073343" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="松桃县妙隘水库投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="182" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 02:37:27" JYLSH="MF17800000034" ZCKZXM="贵州亚坤建设工程有限公司" ZCKZH="2011240001201100047828" ZCKZHKHH="2011240001201100047828" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="保证金 遵义市新浦新区2013年中央财政小型农田水利专项县建设项"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="183" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 01:11:33" JYLSH="MF16300000035" ZCKZXM="中水北方勘测设计研究有限责任公司" ZCKZH="0302060909300026597" ZCKZHKHH="0302060909300026597" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="184" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="60000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 01:23:08" JYLSH="MF16400000043" ZCKZXM="贵州江河监理有限公司" ZCKZH="130012010500025682" ZCKZHKHH="130012010500025682" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="185" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 01:53:14" JYLSH="MF11700000032" ZCKZXM="四川隆生建设工程有限公司" ZCKZH="4402220009100086786" ZCKZHKHH="4402220009100086786" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="遵义市新浦新区2013年中央财政小型农田水利专项县建设项目施工"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="186" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="10000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 02:00:07" JYLSH="MF19500000056" ZCKZXM="铜仁市建筑勘察设计院" ZCKZH="52001683636050005302" ZCKZHKHH="52001683636050005302" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="沿河甘溪水库移民集中安置基础勘察设计"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="187" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 01:05:59" JYLSH="MF11400000075" ZCKZXM="黔西南州协力建设有限公司" ZCKZH="132007838971" ZCKZHKHH="132007838971" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="遵义市新浦区2013年中央财政小型农田水利项目投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="188" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="30000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 02:02:04" JYLSH="MF11900000098" ZCKZXM="贵州黔水工程监理有限责任公司" ZCKZH="23101001040003317" ZCKZHKHH="23101001040003317" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="189" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 01:26:21" JYLSH="MF11000000080" ZCKZXM="贵阳市水利水电勘测设计研究院" ZCKZH="1110422500000252" ZCKZHKHH="1110422500000252" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="190" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 01:29:41" JYLSH="MF19500000090" ZCKZXM="贵阳市水利水电勘测设计研究院" ZCKZH="1110422500000252" ZCKZHKHH="1110422500000252" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="191" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 02:12:32" JYLSH="MF10600000074" ZCKZXM="罗甸县水利有限责任公司" ZCKZH="591001040001706" ZCKZHKHH="591001040001706" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="交遵义市新浦新区２０１３年小农水项目投标保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="192" JYZL="转账" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="30000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 02:22:43" JYLSH="0169400000025" ZCKZXM="遵义神禹科技实业有限责任公司" ZCKZH="0230001000000302" ZCKZHKHH="0230001000000302" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="监理保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="193" JYZL="转账" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="60000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 02:26:05" JYLSH="0169400000026" ZCKZXM="遵义神禹科技实业有限责任公司" ZCKZH="0230001000000302" ZCKZHKHH="0230001000000302" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="监理保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="194" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 02:17:12" JYLSH="MF16600000111" ZCKZXM="贵阳市水利水电勘测设计研究院" ZCKZH="1110422500000252" ZCKZHKHH="1110422500000252" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="保证金"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="195" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="60000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 01:26:56" JYLSH="MF17400000125" ZCKZXM="重庆江河工程建设监理有限公司" ZCKZH="100101040007002" ZCKZHKHH="100101040007002" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="樱桃坪工程"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="196" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="60000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 01:54:39" JYLSH="MF12600000149" ZCKZXM="广东华迪工程建设监理有限公司" ZCKZH="101001519010001135" ZCKZHKHH="101001519010001135" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="黔西县樱桃坪水库工程监理"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="197" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="30000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 02:30:14" JYLSH="MF15700000139" ZCKZXM="广东华迪工程建设监理有限公司" ZCKZH="101001519010001135" ZCKZHKHH="101001519010001135" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="贵州习水县大茅坡水库工程施工监理"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="198" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/28 01:20:01" JYLSH="MF13600000159" ZCKZXM="四川大伟工程建设有限公司" ZCKZH="282581258610001" ZCKZHKHH="282581258610001" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="付投标保证金遵义市新浦新区2013年中央财政小型农田水利专项县"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="199" JYZL="汇兑" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="100000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/29 02:22:39" JYLSH="MF10100000109" ZCKZXM="广东省源天工程公司" ZCKZH="44001541702050099311" ZCKZHKHH="44001541702050099311" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="望谟县桑郎水库工程水电站机电设备采购及安装"/>
    <wlxx BDHM="20160219YH000011100000015" CCXH="5" WLXH="200" JYZL="存现" ZJLX="贷/付" BZ="156" JE="20000.00" JYSJ="2014/05/29 02:06:04" JYLSH="2332900000043" ZCKZXM="" ZCKZH="" ZCKZHKHH="" JYDSYHHH="" JYDSZJLX="" JYDSZJHM="" JYDSTXDZ="" JYDSYZBM="" JYDSLXDH="" BEIZ="福建泰城建设工程公司保证金"/>
```

posted by a web service client, 50 records total but some records can be inserted while others trigger errors. so I guess GBK is not 100% compatible with iso_1? We need to change client data's encoding to UTF-8 in future, what's the best solution to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a while back. Our Java application was trying to submit batched insert statements to the database containing UTF-8 encoded strings (the default for Java), but the Sybase server was configured with ISO-1 character set. The dataserver was Sybase ASE 15.7, and belonging to another team so we could not change its character set to UTF8. Likewise we didn't want to change the character set used by Java either, as we also publish data into an Oracle database which does support UTF-8.

To connect to the Sybase target, we were using Jconnect 7 as our driver.

Since our application was using Spring jdbc template which hides the connection setup, I solved the problem by adding the following connection parameters to the Spring datasource JDBC URL:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:sybase:Tds:<host>:<port>/<database>?APPLICATIONNAME=ourappname&CHARSET=iso_1&DISABLE_UNICHAR_SENDING=true
```